# My error callback is failing with Q Promises

Tags: node.js, promise, q

First time trying to use the Q promises library and I can't get my error callback to work:

```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var Q = require('q');

   var prom =  Q.nfcall(fs.writeFile('daa/write.txt', 'your mom', 'utf-8'));
   prom.then(function(err){
     console.log("error on writing file: ", err);
   });
```

I am deliberately giving a wrong destination to the write function to trigger an error. But on the command line I get this error:

```
fs: missing callback Error: ENOENT, open 'daa/write.txt'"
```

Why is my error callback not getting called? Why is my error callback missing?

Comment: You have to pass the function, not call it :    var prom =  `Q.nfcall(fs.writeFile, 'daa/write.txt', 'your mom', 'utf-8');`

Comment: That solved the problem. Could you write your comment as an answer? I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Sure, I've done that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.nfcall` accepts a function reference and not not the result of a function call.

```
var prom =  Q.nfcall(fs.writeFile, 'daa/write.txt', 'your mom', 'utf-8');
```

You should consider using `Q.denodify` if you intend to call fs more than once. Other libraries like Bluebird ship with a stronger `promisifyAll` function that converts an API to promises.

Comment: Could you tell me when I should be calling `done()` with promises? Does it apply to this example?

Comment: @AmitErandole if you use Bluebird you don't have to use `.done` anywhere since it will detect unhandled rejections itself. With Q you use it to indicate the end of a chain so unhandled rejections propagate.

Comment: Yes please use bluebird before  you get stuck with Q :P

Comment: Has anyone found a bluebird equivalent for the convenience of `nfcall`? I don't want to have to `var promiseWrapped = promisify(myOldFunction)` and then `promiseWrapped(...).then(...)` because it feels like a waste/step backward after "upgrading" to bluebird...

Comment: @JaKXz `fromNode` (`fromCallback` in 3.0) - but don't use it, use promisify _once_ when you get the function initially, or better yet `promisifyAll` so it happens once per API automatically instead of constantly having to wrap things.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to pass the function not call it. Both callbacks work as expected with this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Q = require('q');

var prom =  Q.nfcall(fs.writeFile, 'data/write.txt', 'your mom', 'utf-8');
prom.then(function(){
  console.log('file written');
},function(err){
  console.log("error on writing file: ", err);
});
```